# How to get complete response data based on text field entry Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am facing problem in getting values from rendered data in component that is already outputted on page render. What I need to do is, when someone types in data into text field, it should send it to database but taking that fields data from runtime data.

Currently, when I type something, it says undefined field etc.
This is not form data but a data that need to be update from text field.
So, if user write some xyz in text field, we need to update that data according to the id associated to that field.

I am not able to get data into: console.log(Id, projectId, userId, date, e.target.value)
I have used reduce method that serves the purpose but now I have another use case.

I dont want to set hidden fields as its not the right approach.

The problem is that when someone type data in text field, I need to get that text field data and associated id and respective data from it and pass it ti ajax call.

I need to send that data with ajax but as soon as I type something, it says undefined. I can easily get data from projects array but its of no use to me. I think array reduce method is not good for my use case.

Here is project array:

```
data = [
  {
    "id": 27,
    "projectno": "007823",
    "projectname": "non-A Project 2",
    "dailyproof": 1,
    "probability": "1.0",
    "toleranceregistering": 2,
    "customer_name": "Peter",
    "user_id": "4",
    "days_allocated": "231.0",
    "days_real": "5.0",
    "hours_real": "6.0",
    "project_times": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "activity": "\"yht\"",
        "date": "2020-04-28",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 27,
        "token": "\"trr\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:36:55.479Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:36:55.479Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "activity": "\"yht\"",
        "date": "2020-04-03",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 27,
        "token": "\"trr\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:37:08.763Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:37:08.763Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "activity": "\"yht\"",
        "date": "2020-04-14",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 27,
        "token": "\"dfg\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:37:19.177Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:37:19.177Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "projectno": "007333",
    "projectname": "non-A Project 2",
    "dailyproof": 0,
    "probability": "1.0",
    "toleranceregistering": 2,
    "customer_name": "Peter",
    "user_id": "4",
    "days_allocated": "231.0",
    "days_real": "3.333333333333333333333333334",
    "hours_real": "4.0",
    "project_times": [
      {
        "id": 18,
        "activity": "\"tgr\"",
        "date": "2020-04-16",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 28,
        "token": "\"ujy\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:39:41.465Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:39:41.465Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "activity": "\"ddd\"",
        "date": "2020-04-11",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 28,
        "token": "\"fff\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:39:55.020Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:39:55.020Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "projectno": "00721",
    "projectname": "non-A Project 2",
    "dailyproof": 1,
    "probability": "1.0",
    "toleranceregistering": 2,
    "customer_name": "Peter",
    "user_id": "4",
    "days_allocated": "231.0",
    "days_real": "5.0",
    "hours_real": "6.0",
    "project_times": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "activity": "\"cdf\"",
        "date": "2020-04-11",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 29,
        "token": "\"fgff\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:26.392Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:26.392Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "activity": "\"tg\"",
        "date": "2020-04-15",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 29,
        "token": "\"ad\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:38.747Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:38.747Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "activity": "\"ff\"",
        "date": "2020-04-19",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 29,
        "token": "\"bbb\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:47.500Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:41:47.500Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "projectno": "0074",
    "projectname": "non-A Project 2",
    "dailyproof": 1,
    "probability": "1.0",
    "toleranceregistering": 2,
    "customer_name": "Peter",
    "user_id": "4",
    "days_allocated": "231.0",
    "days_real": "3.333333333333333333333333334",
    "hours_real": "4.0",
    "project_times": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "activity": "\"ff\"",
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 30,
        "token": "\"bbb\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:42:09.385Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:42:09.385Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "activity": "\"rter\"",
        "date": "2020-04-19",
        "hours": "2.0",
        "project_id": 30,
        "token": "\"gfdg\"",
        "user_id": 4,
        "created_at": "2020-04-22T12:42:19.861Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-04-22T12:42:19.861Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]

getDaysNumber('2020', '04') {
        const dayNums = [];
        const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            dayNums.push(i);
            // console.log(i, ' xxx ');
        }
        return dayNums;
    }

{


data.map((h, index) => (
                                    <TableRow key={`mi-${index}`}>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.projectno}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.projectname}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.customer_name}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.days_allocated}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.days_real}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">{h.hours_real}</TableCell>
                                        {daysNumber.reduce((acc, number, index) => {
                                            const found = h.project_times.find(item => number == item["date"].split('-')[2].replace(/^0+/, ''))
                                            const Id = found && found["id"];
                                            const projectId = found && found["project_id"];
                                            const userId = found && found["user_id"];
                                            const date = found && found["date"];
                                            const hours = found && found["hours"];
                                            found && console.log(Id, projectId, userId, date);
                                            return [...acc,
                                                h.dailyproof == 1 && hours > 0.0 ?
                                                    <TableCell align="right" key={`mi-${index}`}
                                                               onClick={this.launchCreateContactDialog}>{hours}</TableCell>
                                                    :
                                                    <TableCell align="right" key={`mi-${index}`}>
                                                        <TextField required fullWidth size="small"
                                                                   variant="outlined"
                                                                   onKeyUp={(e) => console.log(Id, projectId, userId, date, e.target.value)}/>
                                                    </TableCell>
                                            ]
                                        }, [])
                                        }
                                    </TableRow>
                                ))
                            }
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. What do you mean by "when I type something, it says undefined field?" Are you getting an error? If so, what's the exact error? Your code references variables like `h`, but that's not provided so we don't know what it is.

Comment: @Jacob I have added data and explanations as well. Does that work please?

Comment: The very first line of code I'm looking at, `const found = h.project_times...` references a variable `h` which is still not defined in your code description. Is `h` one of the projects in your project array? Is `daysNumber` a return value from `getDaysNumber`?

Comment: Yes that right dayNumber get 1 to 30 values from getDaysNumber

Comment: I am not getting any error but I need to check which field was clicked and updated so i must get the id of that field and update it in database. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `find` call may sometimes return `undefined`.

```
const found = h.project_times.find(item => number == item["date"]
  .split('-')[2]
  .replace(/^0+/, '')
)
```

This is expected when no matches are found. And since it's undefined, all of these will also end up `undefined`:

```
const Id = found && found["id"];
const projectId = found && found["project_id"];
const userId = found && found["user_id"];
const date = found && found["date"];
const hours = found && found["hours"];
```

Therefore, it's not unusual that your `console.log` statement will log out the value `undefined`.

It sounds like you're needing to do a few things:

1. Maintain this data as *state* in your component.
2. Add a function to mutate this state.
3. Add a function to store the state (calling an API)

I don't have enough context to answer #3 for you, but here's the type of pattern you want to go for:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function HoursEntry() {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Do your data fetching here; for now will use your constant
    setState(data);
  }, []);

  function updateHours({ userId, projectId, hourEntryId, date, hours }) {
    // Build newData based on the changes...
    setState(newData);
  }

  // All the rendering stuff. Rendered components should be mappings of what's in
  // state...
    <TextField 
      required fullWidth
      size="small"
      variant="outlined"
      value={hours}
      onChange={(e) => updateHours({ 
        userId, 
        projectId, 
        hourEntryId: Id, 
        date, 
        hours: parseFloat(e.target.value)
      })}/>
  // ...
}
```

Inside of your `updateHours` function, you'll create a new copy of your data with the expected modifications. For example, if you're updating an existing object, you'll update its `hours` property. If you're updating something for which there is no record, you'll create a new one, etc. The key is your call to `setState` to update the data in your component.

Then, once you have your submit button or whatever method you've got to store, you'll reference this state for the latest copy of your data.

That's the general pattern for any kind of form entry component; it's an exercise in updating state.

Comment: But the thing is that If I do `console.log(h.projectno, h.project_id, h.user_id, e.target.value)}` it works fine. I need to get data from `daysNumber.reduce` thing. So you are right but its not an obvious issue.

Comment: It's not clear what your code is trying to do; what is your expected behavior if there is no matching project time for the day of month?

Comment: If there is no time match, I need to update that record using text field and I just need to check which text field was being update and then upon that i need to send id, project_id from project_times array to database.

Comment: You understood correctly what my code is doing, but the problem is that, when there is no matching for hours found, i need to update the hour for that day in the database. So i clicked the text field and write something and i can get its data in functions but i am unable to get the ids and other thing so i can see which records needs updation of hours based on id. does tht make sense?

Comment: As in inserting a new object in `project_times`?

Comment: const Id = found && found["id"]; I want this in my function. Did you get it?

Comment: Tried to explain things for you. I'm still vague on what you're getting stuck on, but hopefully this'll help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time on it. It didn't solve my problem but gonna accept it as answer for your efforts. :) As I am not using hooks in my project.